# ListViewBuilder problem when i run my code on emulatior. its shows that "Bottom over flowed by 167 pixels"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my emulator image which is showing the problem, I also use my mobile but it same condition

[image]

I having problems when my container height is more than 100. I can solve my problem by using `SingleChildScrollView`. But I want to scroll my only my list portion and that's why I don't wanna use `SingleChildScrollView`. Will my container size increase or container height increase show any render problem?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../models/transaction.dart';

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transaction;
  TransactionList(this.transaction);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
      height: 200,
      // height: 300, when i use 300 then the problem occures.
     
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.purple,
                      width: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text(
                    '\$${transaction[index].amount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.purple,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      transaction[index].title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transaction[index].date),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: transaction.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your MainScreen  with SingleChildScollView Widget

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I know that but then my whole screen will be scrollable. I just want my List will be scrollable that's why I am searching for the solution,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. But now my whole screen is scrollable. but it's ok now. I will manage. I add SingleChildScroll... in my main. Now it's ok to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).